# How can you force nested flexboxes to fill a desired space?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var tag = document.createElement("div");

var element = document.getElementById("container");


for(let i = 1; i<17; i++){
    
    var tag = document.createElement("div");
    tag.setAttribute('id', `row`)
    tag.setAttribute('tag', `parent`)
    element.appendChild(tag);
    var elements = document.getElementById(`row`)
    for(let j = 1; j<17; j++){
        var tags = document.createElement("div");
        tags.setAttribute('id', `${j}`)
        tags.setAttribute('cell', `yes`)
        tags.setAttribute('parent', `${i}`)
        elements.appendChild(tags)
        elements.removeAttribute("id")
        //console.log(elements)
        
     }
}
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('parent')
    addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    const selectedCell = e.path[0]
    //console.log(selectedCell.getAttribute('parent'))
    //console.log(typeof selectedCell.getAttribute('parent'))
    if(typeof selectedCell.getAttribute('parent') === 'string'){
        selectedCell.setAttribute('selected', 'true')
        //console.log(selectedCell)
    }
    
})
```

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: baseline;
    align-content: stretch;
    height: 960px;
    width: 960px;
}
div[tag]{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
[tag] > [id]{
    display: flex;
    height: 60px;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

div[selected]{
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">

    </div>
<script src = "app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am currently on the tail end of the introductory front-end course from OdinProject, however, I am stuck on the etch-a-sketch assignment. The CSS (located below) will only fill out properly if I set a fixed height in pixels.

```
div#container {
    border-color: red;
    height: 960px;
    width: 960px;
    flex-direction: row;
}
div[tag*="parent"]{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
div[cell*="yes"]{
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-grow: 1;
    
}

div[selected]{
    background-color: black;
}
```

If I set the height to auto (as present in the current styling), the width is fine, which is 960 pixels, but the height of the rows and the cells will be 0 pixels. Setting the height as a fixed height is okay in this scenario which is a 16x16 etch-a-sketch, however, I am planning to allow the user to select the number of cells, which would require the height to be dynamic. I have tried everything and nothing seems to work. This is my first question here, so I don't know if you will require the other code, so I will just paste it below.

```
var tag = document.createElement("div");

var element = document.getElementById("container");


for(let i = 1; i<17; i++){
    
    var tag = document.createElement("div");
    tag.setAttribute('id', `row`)
    tag.setAttribute('tag', `parent`)
    element.appendChild(tag);
    var elements = document.getElementById(`row`)
    for(let j = 1; j<17; j++){
        var tags = document.createElement("div");
        tags.setAttribute('id', `${j}`)
        tags.setAttribute('cell', `yes`)
        tags.setAttribute('parent', `${i}`)
        elements.appendChild(tags)
        elements.removeAttribute("id")
        console.log(elements)
        
     }
}
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('parent')
    addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    const selectedCell = e.path[0]
    //console.log(selectedCell.getAttribute('parent'))
    console.log(typeof selectedCell.getAttribute('parent'))
    if(typeof selectedCell.getAttribute('parent') === 'string'){
        selectedCell.setAttribute('selected', 'true')
        console.log(selectedCell)
    }
    
})
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">

    </div>
<script src = "app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding a `min-height` to the cells. As they have no content their initial height will be 0px

Comment: @Michel adding a min-height value just makes the cells that height and don't fill out the container flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `height` and `width` on `div#container` to `100vh` and `100vw`. This is so that the container fills the whole viewport, which is what you want as I understand.

I removed the `height:auto` on the parent and cell classes and I also removed `width:100%`

I created a variable called `gridSize` with `let`. I replaced the `17` with this variable `gridSize` in the two loops and I added the following to calculate the `height` of the cell:

```js
let cellHeight = Math.floor((100 / gridSize) * 1000) / 1000 + "vh";
```

And, then I set the `height` of the cell dynamically with:

```js
tags.style.height = gridSize
```

which effectively is the same as:

```js
tags.style.height = "10vh" // if gridSize is 10
tags.style.height = "5vh"  // if gridSize is 20
```

You should be able to implement the functionality to allow the user to dynamically select the grid size. This demo should show you the way forward.

```js
var tag = document.createElement("div");
var element = document.getElementById("container");
let gridSize = 17;
let cellHeight = Math.floor((100 / gridSize) * 1000) / 1000 + "vh";

for (let i = 1; i < gridSize; i++) {
  var tag = document.createElement("div");
  tag.setAttribute('id', `row`)
  tag.setAttribute('tag', `parent`)
  element.appendChild(tag);
  var elements = document.getElementById(`row`)
  for (let j = 1; j < gridSize; j++) {
    var tags = document.createElement("div");
    tags.setAttribute('id', `${j}`)
    tags.setAttribute('cell', `yes`)
    tags.setAttribute('parent', `${i}`)
    tags.style.height = cellHeight;
    elements.appendChild(tags)
    elements.removeAttribute("id")
  }
}

var cells = document.querySelectorAll('parent')
addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  const selectedCell = e.path[0]
  if (typeof selectedCell.getAttribute('parent') === 'string') {
    selectedCell.setAttribute('selected', 'true')
  }
})
```

```css
div#container {
  border-color: red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  flex-direction: row;
}

div[tag*="parent"] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

div[cell*="yes"] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

div[selected] {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```